Installing Android Apps in Ubuntu ARaspberry Pi
Is it possible to install Android Apps in Ubuntu?
Most of the times answer I got from various forums in NO.
Because android is designed for ARM processor or android packages can not be installed on PC x86 without emulator.
My question is that Ubuntu is now available for Raspberry Pi which uses ARM processor. Can we install android apps in Ubuntu for Rpi?
IF yes, what is  the process?
if no, why?

No, you cannot run Android applications on an RPi running Ubuntu.  The archs may be similar, but there is no emulation layer to handle the Android syscalls.

I have no idea why this legitimate question is downvoted.

You can run Waydroid, which is available for ARM https://waydro.id/#install
